# What does symbol tilde (~) mean in CSS

Tags: css, tilde

I want to know what does (~) mean in css.

```
#img1:hover ~ #img2 {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

In visual studio, i get 'unexpected character sequence' error when i use this symbol. what is the actual meaning of this in CSS. what does it do?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

> **8.3.2. General sibling combinator**
>
> The general sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~)
>   character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
>   elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the
>   document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the
>   second one.

**example**

```
h1 ~ pre
```

matches that `<pre>` here:

```
<h1>Definition of the function a</h1>
<p>Function a(x) has to be applied to all figures in the table.</p>
<pre>function a(x) = 12x/13.5</pre>
```

There is also `+` selector, for adjacent sibling combinator: with `h1 + pre` the `<pre>` tag would have to be right after `<h1>`

Answer (score 29):

It applies the style to all elements matching the second selector if they appear after the elements matching the first selector. For example, given an HTML snippet and CSS rule:

```css
hr ~ p {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Line one</p>
<hr />
<p>Line two</p>
<p>Line three</p>
```

only `<p>Line two</p>` and `<p>Line three</p>` will appear bold. In your example, I think Visual Studio is having a problem interpreting the `:hover` modifier, since it isn't really an element. If you remove it from the rule, it may work correctly.

Comment: Have you noticed any issues using ~ in various browsers? Latest Chrome seems to ignore it for me.

Comment: I built a very simple [index.html] containing only the above example. It displayed correctly, so I opened the About page to get the version number to report back to you. I was on Chrome 70, but navigating to the page started the update process. When it finished, I relaunched and tried it again. So, I can say it works in Chrome 70 and 71. You might want to make sure nothing is overriding your styles.