# CSS: is there a way to do a conditional nth-child

Tags: css

I want to use css to select all elements until it reaches an element with a specific attribute. i.e.:

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li class="active">...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

I need to catch all `<li>` elements that appear before the `active` one. I know how to catch any group of child elements using nth-child etc., but `active` changes, so it can't be a static group. And I know I can do it through javascript, but I wan't a css solution.

So is this possible to select all child elements up to a calculated point? Or in other words: **is there a way to do a conditional nth-child?** I'm willing to change the markup if needed (the attribute doesn't have to be a class, it can be anything).

Until recently I would've thought it's not possible, but after learning about the css [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) I know it's possible to access the DOM attributes, so maybe it's also possible to take it a step further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override css by doing this:

```
ul > li{
    /* normal styling for li above active */
}

ul > li.active ~ li{
    /* overriding the above stylings for elements after li.active element */
}
```

if the attribute is not class then you can do `ul > li[attrName="active"] ~ li`.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fsjf4/1/)**

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fsjf4/2/)** (*if "active" is in other attribute*)

Comment: Beautiful, just beutiful. Can you explain to me why the `~` does this? I'm familiar with using `+`, and I've read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471382/what-does-mean-in-css) but I'm not getting what's going on here? What's the difference from the `+`?

Comment: Yes it is a general sibling element which is selecting all the `li` elements which are after the `li` with `active` class/attrName. At first, I applied a common styling to all the `li` elements, then I overrided or gave special styling to the sibling elements of `li.active` by overriding.

Comment: I get the general idea. What's confusing me is that `~` supposedly matches all direct siblings. It's not the opposite of `+`, right? How does it not apply to the adjacent `li`?

Comment: @yuvi each element has only 2 direct siblings, the previous sibling and the next one. `~` is designed to do so and it does not relate to how `+` works, I think.

Comment: @yuvi It did apply also to the adjacent `li`. sorry I am not getting your point..

Comment: @Mr_Green Nevermind. The behavior is just still confusing me a little, I'm trying to understand the difference of `~` from `+`... I'll just keep reading about it until I get it. Thanks for your patience

Comment: @yuvi `~` applies styling to all the next sibling elements whereas `+` applies styling to only the adjacent sibling element. ignore this if you are asking something else :)

Comment: So `+` only applies to the next sibling, and `~` applies to *all* of the next siblings?

Comment: Great. That clarifies it, Thanks!