# Difference between + and ~ in css

Tags: css

What is the difference between both below. I see no difference in appearance after toggling.

```
h1 + h2
h1 ~ h2
```

Can someone please explain simple ?

Comment: Please research before asking questions.  This can easily be searched for.

Comment: "after toggling"? Read the manual to learn what they do.

Comment: Everything you need to know is [right here](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/).

Comment: Please read this: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Comment: E + F an F element immediately preceded by an E element Adjacent sibling combinator.

E ~ F an F element preceded by an E element. Also, refer to this post :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471382/what-does-mean-in-css

Comment: thank you all
I know I should have done some more research.
@APAD1 's made it so simple.

Answer (score 0):

### `+` is for adjacent siblings

[image]

### `~` is for general siblings

[image]

## [**Source**](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)